# Cannot display alert message

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to create a simple login page which only consist of one valid username and password. Hence I do not need to use MySQL to store other valid usernames and password.

I cannot get the alert message to display after clicking on the button.
Anyone know what is the problem?
When I click on the button, all the page does is refresh itself erasing any entries I previously made.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
     $('input[type="email"]').keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
           $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
        }
     });
    $('#loginButton').click(function() {
        var ValidUser = $('#usernameInput').val() === 'admin@company.com';
        var ValidPassword = $('#passwordInput').val() === 'dogcat';
        if (ValidEmail === true && ValidPassword === true)
        {
            alert("Login Successful");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Incorrect Username/Password");
        }
    });
});
</script>

<title>Login</title>

</head>

<body>
<div id="loginMenu">
<span>
<form id="formLogin" name="login">
<Label>Username:</Label>
<br/>
<input id="usernameInput" name = "username" type="email" required="required">
<br/>
<label>Password:</label>
<br/>
<input id="passwordInput" name="password" type="password" required="required">
<br/>
<input id="loginButton" type="submit" value="Log In">
</form>
</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Replace `ValidEmail` with `ValidUser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you press F12 in your browser, you will see if there is any error with your code. In your case, it turned out you are using variable `ValidEmail` which is not defined. Use `ValidUser` instead and you will see your alerts. Here is a [punker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/uz3hfjBazujss3y2NT48) I setup for your code.

I am also assuming yours is a test page not a production code.

Comment: Glad I could help!